# How to configure construction heuristic and local search in timefold configuration for creating solver

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner, timefold

```
<constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch>
        <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
    </localSearch>
```

Earlier, I was using the solver.xml file to configure the solver. However, now there are some methods in timefold that allow us to configure the solver using Java. How can I incorporate the configuration into the code below?

```
`var solverConfig= new SolverConfig()
                    .withSolutionClass(EventBinAssignation.class)
                    .withEntityClasses(Event.class)
                    .withEntityClasses(BinAvailablity.class)
                    .withConstraintProviderClass(OptaPlannerConstraintProvider.class)

                    // The solver runs only for 5 seconds on this small dataset.
                    // It's recommended to run for at least 5 minutes ("5m") otherwise.
                    .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(5));



            SolverFactory<EventBinAssignation> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig); 
`
```

I am not able to find method so that i can add configuration of local-search and construction-heuristic

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this (i don't know if it is necessary to specify the solution, entity and constraints classes as Timefold should know how to deal with them):

```
var template = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("your/path/to/the/SolverConfig.xml");

    var solverConfig= new SolverConfig(template)
                        .withSolutionClass(EventBinAssignation.class)
                        .withEntityClasses(Event.class)
                        .withEntityClasses(BinAvailablity.class)
                        .withConstraintProviderClass(OptaPlannerConstraintProvider.class)
    
                        // The solver runs only for 5 seconds on this small dataset.
                        // It's recommended to run for at least 5 minutes ("5m") otherwise.
                        .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    
    
    
                SolverFactory<EventBinAssignation> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
```

You can also use setters to specify some properties to the solverConfig.
You can use the following link as references:
[How can you switch between the algorithms of Timefold Solver in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996534/how-can-you-switch-between-the-algorithms-of-timefold-solver-in-spring-boot) and https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/configuration

**Updated answer:** I saw that you can configure in application.properties something like this (https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/blob/stable/technology/java-spring-boot/src/main/resources/application.properties):

```
# XML file for power tweaking, defaults to solverConfig.xml (directly under src/main/resources)
# timefold.solver-config-xml=org/.../timeTableSolverConfig.xml
```

So it is no longer necessary to configure by code where to get the configuration of the algorithm.

Please let me know if this answer helped you.