# How can you switch between the algorithms of Timefold Solver in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timefold

In the Timefold Solver documentation it is mentioned that several types of algorithms can be used to solve a certain problem. How can this be configured in Spring Boot to be able to compare the performances of the algorithms or to perform various tests?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation describes a property](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/integration/integration#integrationWithSpringBootProperties) called `timefold.solver.solver-config-xml`. It allows you to specify a [full solver config XML](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/configuration#solverConfigurationByXML) in which you can configure every aspect of the solver. You can also build the `SolverConfig` as a POJO and build the solver from it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a `src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml` (the default location of `timefold.solver.solver-config-xml`) and configure it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">

    <constructionHeuristic/>
    <localSearch/>
</solver>
```

No need to specify the entityClass elements etc, the Timefold Spring Boot starter will take care of that for you.

---

That being said, the best way to benchmark different algorithms, is to use the `timefold-solver-benchmark` module (see docs).

Comment: The docs really lack an example how to run the benchmarker with Spring. Feel free to create an issue for that.